# Deeplink to Ember app from outside

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

How can I deeplink to my Ember app from outside ?
Say I want to deeplink to within my ember route (mainPage\deepRoute)

So when user clicks on the external link (not part of my Ember app), he is directly taken to mainPage\deepRoute

How will I code such a link ?

I assume by default the Ember application template would be rendered, but I want to direct route to some other link/template ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply link inside to any route of your Ember.js app directly, however your webserver has to be configured with url redirect to the `index.html`.

For example, if you use nginx as a webserver, you should have something like this in your nginx config file:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

**Option Two**: if you cannot update the webserver, for example, you use GitHub pages, you have to use the #-ed url option. In this case, a url looks like this: example.com/#/posts/1/comments

More info here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server will load the single Ember html page for that url.  You can create a 'catchall' route in your web framework that aliases (not redirects to) your index.html view, - probably at the bottom of your server route definitions - or manually alias whichever specific route you are concerned with.

Then once Ember is loaded it will enter the route specified in the url and use any query params that were specified.